# International Geocoding from Postal Code

Tags: geocode, yahoo-api, google-geocoder, bing-maps

I'm trying to develop an addressing solution where a user can input a postal code and the City, State, and Country are automatically filled in. This is obviously straightfoward for a given locale/culture setting depending on the service, but I'm trying to manage this for international lookups. For example, the postal code 10104 maps to (at the very least), New York City USA, San Jose Costa Rica, and a region in France. I need to be able to throw the postal code at a service and return all matches which I can provide to the user to select from. As far as I can tell, this is not easily manageable from the 3 major geocode services (Google, Bing, Yahoo), but I'm hoping I'm missing something. Any help in getting this moving would be much appreciated.

Comment: There are multiple possibilities but you can use for example Google Maps Places API to get help and result using only postal codes: https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete#place_types